# Repetir X veces imágenes en ciclo for PHP

Tags: php

El código consiste en repetir *X* veces imágenes que están leyéndose en una carpeta del servidor. Pero no se cómo hacer que se repitan, ya que con el ciclo *while*, el cual lee las imágenes de los archivos, no repite las veces que quiero y dentro hay un *for*. Lo siento si no me explico bien, os dejo lo que he intentado yo. Muchas gracias!!

```
    $filehandle = opendir($ruta); // Abrir archivos de la carpeta
        while($file = readdir($filehandle)){
            for($i=0; $i<=$numVecesRep; $i++){
                if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                    $tamanyo = GetImageSize($ruta . $file);
                    echo "<img style = 'padding: 3px; border: 2px solid #C9C7C7' src='$ruta$file' $tamanyo[3]>";

                    $patron = "/I_(.*)_IH_(.*)_HP_(.*)_PN_(.*)_N\./";
                    $result = preg_match($patron, $file, $resultados);

                    $nombreCompleto = $resultados[0];
                    $vecesMostrar = $resultados[1];
                    $horariosProhibidos = $resultados[2];
                    $periodo = $resultados[3];
                    $nombre = $resultados[4];
                    //Llamo a la función que se encarga de agregar los registros
                    agregarImpresiones($nombre,$ruta, $vecesMostrar, $horariosProhibidos, $periodo);
                    impresionesTotales($nombre, $ruta, $periodo, $vecesMostrar);
                }//end if
            }//end for
        }//end while

    closedir($filehandle); // Fin lectura archivos
```

Comment: Disculpa pero dentro del _for_ no hay ningún _while_, ¿puedes explicarte mejor?

Comment: Y ya puestos... poner bien el código formateado ;)

Comment: @track3r lo siento, quería decir un for dentro de un while, pero igualmente no me funciona ninguna de las dos...

Comment: @VeraCanet lo siento, es que sigo sin entender mucho como se hacen las cosas en Stackoverflow. Voy a intentar ponerlo bien :)

Comment: Bien, ya tenemos el código legible, ahora sólo falta que expliques exactamente qué es lo que quieres.

Lo que yo he entendido es: Tienes una carpeta con X archivos, y necesitas que se lea la carpeta y se pinte en pantalla Y veces cada archivo, pero cada archivo se puede imprimir un número de veces distinto del otro fichero. Por ejemplo, file1.jpg se necesita imprimir 3 veces pero file2.jpg necesita imprimirse 5.

Estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: Exacto! @VeraCanet

Comment: Y de dónde sacas el número de veces que necesita imprimirse file1, file2, file3?.... en qué variable o en qué dato se guarda ese valor?

Necesitas tener una correlación de "file1.jpg -> 2 veces", "file2.jpg" -> 7 veces. Esto con un array por ejemplo, o desde una base de datos...

Comment: @VeraCanet tengo una base de datos con el numero de veces que tengo que mostrar la imagen

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error? lo digo porque cuando pones $tamanyo[3] en la img, debería ser algo así como: width="$tamanyo[3]" si es que $tamanyo[3] contiene el width.

Comment: Sí, eso también lo debería mirar, pero el problema que tenía es que hace el for nada más entrar al while, en vez de hacerlo cuando ya sabe cuántas veces tenía que imprimir esa imagen en pantalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces algo como esto debería servirte

```
$filehandle = opendir($ruta); // Abrir archivos de la carpeta
  //lista de todos los ficheros encontrados
  while($file = readdir($filehandle)){
    //saltamos los ficheros . y ..
    if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
      //capturamos datos del fichero actual
      $tamanyo = GetImageSize($ruta . $file);
      echo "<img style = 'padding: 3px; border: 2px solid #C9C7C7' src='$ruta$file' $tamanyo[3]>";

      $patron = "/I_(.*)_IH_(.*)_HP_(.*)_PN_(.*)_N\./";
      $result = preg_match($patron, $file, $resultados);

      $nombreCompleto = $resultados[0];
      $vecesMostrar = $resultados[1];

      $horariosProhibidos = $resultados[2];
      $periodo = $resultados[3];
      $nombre = $resultados[4];
      //Llamo a la función que se encarga de agregar los registros
      agregarImpresiones($nombre,$ruta, $vecesMostrar, $horariosProhibidos, $periodo);
      impresionesTotales($nombre, $ruta, $periodo, $vecesMostrar);


      //aqui es donde debes hacer el FOR para imprimir X veces
      for ($x = 1; $x <= $vecesMostrar; $x++ ) {
        //imprimir imagen
      }


    }//end if
  }//end while

closedir($filehandle); // Fin lectura archivos
```

Las dos funciones que ya tenías desconozco lo que hacen, pero vamos, que esta estructura debería imprimirte cada imagen las X veces que recoges en $vecesMostrar