# Tabla con filas y columnas determinadas PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una especie de "galería" en PHP (que lee y muestra las fotos del servidor) en la que hay un formulario principal dónde tú eliges el número de filas y el número de columnas y que si por ejemplo pongo 2 columnas y 3 filas (en total 6 celdas) y en el servidor tengo 100 imágenes, que solo me muestre esas 6 y no todas las que están en el servidor. Lo que he intentado es hacer una tabla con un ciclo `for` en las columnas y filas, pero no me sale, me muestra todas las imágenes. Lo siento si no me he explicado bien, aquí os dejo el código:

```
//Leer número archivos de la carpeta según lo indicado

//Bucle para seleccionar filas y columnas

for($i=0; $i<=$numFilas; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($w=0; $w<=$numColumnas; $w++){
        echo "<td>";
        while( /*$i<=$numImagenes+1 && */$file = readdir($filehandle)){
            if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                $tamanyo = GetImageSize($ruta . $file);

                echo "<td><img style = 'padding: 3px; border: 2px solid #A9FF93' src='$ruta$file' $tamanyo[3]></td>";

                $patron = "/I_(.*)_IH_(.*)_HP_(.*)_PN_(.*)_N\./";
                $result = preg_match($patron, $file, $resultados);

                $nombreCompleto = $resultados[0];
                $vecesMostrar = $resultados[1];
                $horariosProhibidos = $resultados[2];
                $periodo = $resultados[3];
                $nombre = $resultados[4];

                //Llamo a la función que se encarga de agregar los registros
                agregarImpresiones($nombre,$ruta, $vecesMostrar, $horariosProhibidos, $periodo);
                impresionesTotales($nombre, $ruta, $periodo, $vecesMostrar);
                    mostrarXVeces($nombre);
            }//end if
            //$i++;
        }//end while
        echo "</td>";                           
    }//end for
    echo "</tr>";
}//end for`
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Duplicado de [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162074/repetir-x-veces-im%C3%A1genes-en-ciclo-for-php/162084#162084). Creo que deberías seguir con el hilo inicial.

Comment: @veracanet Hola! No, no es un duplicado, es diferente al de ayer ;)

Comment: Vale, ya sé cuál era el fallo. Antes me salían todas las imágenes que tenía guardadas en el servidor repitiéndose todo el rato, pero lo que he hecho ha sido cortar el while con un break y ya me funciona :)